# android widget size differs from its library project

Tags: android, android-widget

I have created a library project. As a normal app it runs as expected. If I check it as a library project and create a new project which uses this library everything works as expexted except my widget.

In the new app I do not have anything in the res folder just the values/strings.xml file. So everything else should be used from the library project.

Still the original app has a 4*2 widget, the new has 4*3.

Any ideas why?

Here is a part of my manifest file

```
<receiver 
     android:label="@string/app_name" 
     android:name="cc.webmania.android.mylibrary.TheWidget">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
     </intent-filter>
     <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info"/>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rebuild your projects, maybe R file was generated badly. Another thought is that you set bad widget width in your `widget_info.xml`. Can you show it?

To have widget with 2 cells you should set min width/height to 110dp. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#anatomy) you can find some helpful tips.

Comment: rebuild did not helped.

Here is my widget_info.xml at the library project
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <appwidget-provider
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:minWidth="292dp"
 android:minHeight="146dp"
 android:updatePeriodMillis="12000000"
 android:initialLayout="@layout/bolcsesseg_widget"
 android:label="@string/app_name"/>

Comment: Try to set android:minHeight="110dp" or just lower then 146

Comment: I changed it to 140 and now I get the same for the base and for the new app. Thanks